# How to know whether electric field is rotating without divergence? (basic question)

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, vector-fields, vortex

Sorry for my broken English.

I`m a physics undergrad and frankly know nothing about the subject yet.
Today I was told by my professor that if electric field becomes weaker as it goes further from the point charge in the picture, it actually is not rotating even if it looks as if it is rotating in the picture(He showed us some simple picture of arrows rotating and their length becomes shorter as it goes further from the center).

and he said that you can say whether its rotating or not by imagining something like a windmill to which plus charges are detached and visualize whether it rotates or not. But I could not fully understand it. I`m still thinking about it but still have no idea.

Can anybody explain this to me please?

*)The "windmill" he referred to actually looks like a cross and plus charges were detached to the each end of the bar). You put that cross in the field and if you think it rotates, then the field rotates. This is what he said as far as I recall.

**)the picture he showed us looks like this but in what he showed, the arrows gets shorter as it gets further from the center:

[image]

He also said if it gets longer like the picture below, it rotates.

[image]

Comment: Can you link the picture? Without the picture it's hard to know what you mean.

Comment: Sorry I don`t have the image file. but its a very simple picture. just vectors rotating drawing circles but the length gets shorter as it gets further from the center.

Comment: That sounds like a vector field with a non-zero curl ([this is what I mean by *curl*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics))). In that case we would normally say the vector field was rotating.

Comment: I've added what I think is the picture you are describing. Feel free to roll back my edit if this isn't what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so your professor is talking about the curl operator which is to do with infinitesimal rotation not macroscopic rotation.  This means that if we imaging the vector field was water with arrows representing the speed at a given point and we a place a ball/paddle wheel in the water, would it rotate about its centre.

In the top diagram it would not rotate, however, it would move in a large circle. Using the word rotate in this way is maybe a bit of a colloquialism and not helpful.  Wheat he means is that there is no curl.

So curl is to do with how something would rotate about its centre, not the path it would follow.

Comment: Thanks a lot Toby, so you mean curl refers to local rotation, not the whole path, right? your explanation was helpful, but if you don't mind, can you explain about the "cross with plus charges detached"? why does it not rotate in the field above but it does in the below?

Comment: In the bottom field, it will rotate at every point, as the outside vectors are greater.  In the top field it will move in a circle but not rotate as the outside vectors are smaller (however it will rotate in the centre).  I just found this video that might be useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB83DpBJQsE